# Registration form throws an Internal Server Error when submitted

Tags: java, jsp, error-handling, internal-server-error, http-status-code-500

I've made a registration form using JSP but whenever i try to submit it, it gives an error 500 internal server error.
[here's an image for the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3WGN.png)

Here's my jsp code

```
<%
    String fname = request.getParameter("firstName");
    String lname = request.getParameter("lastName");
    String gender = request.getParameter("Gender");
    String telephone = request.getParameter("Telephone");
    String address = request.getParameter("Address");
    String course = request.getParameter("Course");

    Connection conn = null;
    Statement st = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); 
        conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Register?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC","IN0719A33A","iD7ErqoRO");
        st = conn.createStatement();

        String qry = "INSERT INTO `Registration` (`ID`, `First Name`, `Last Name`, `Gender`, `Phone no.`, `Address`, `Course`) VALUES (NULL, '"+ fname + "', '" + lname + "', '" + gender + "', '" + telephone + "', '" + address + "', '"+ course + "');";

        st.executeUpdate(qry);
        %>
        <jsp:forward page="Thankyou.html"/>
        <%
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        out.print(ex.getMessage());
    }
%>
```

Comment: It looks like you are missing the JDBC driver. The JAR file with the JDBC driver must be either in `WEB-INF/lib` folder of your application, or in Tomcat's `lib` folder.

Comment: actually i've uploaded all the contents of the Web Content folder on the server and my jar file was already there in lib folder.